# Random image display

Tags: php, random

I have a list of images that need to be displayed. However theres only space for 5. I need to display 5 of these at a time randomly.

Whats the best way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have the list of images in an array, you could use [shuffle()](http://www.php.net/shuffle).

Answer (score 4):

There are plenty of ways to achive this.

One example lets say you have all the image names in an array then you could:

```
$images = array('imgAbc.jpg', 'img123.jpg'.... 'imgXYZ.gif');

//randomize the array
shuffle($images);

//then just get the 5 elements you want:
array_slice($images, 4);
```

Other way could be if your images have numbers you could just generate 5 random numbers, etc. etc.

As I said there are several ways to do it.