# How do I rotate two images in wordpress sidebar?

Tags: php

I think (hope) my question is simpler than how I've phrased it, but this is also why I'm coming up empty on Google. It's similar to this, but I need to handle some HTML with it and am a little unclear: [Random image display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080787/random-image-display)

In the sidebar of my Wordpress install I have two images in this order:

```
<a href="http://www.link1.tld"><img src="files/image1.jpg" border="0" /></a>
<a href="http://www.link2.tld"><img src="files/image2.jpg" border="0" /></a>
```

What's the easiest way to accomplish rotating this order when the page is refreshed (so that the order will be image2 / image1)? And upon next refresh, go back to image1 / image2?

Comment: Do you want it to always rotate or be random?

Comment: Ideally I'd like it to rotate -- I've updated the title to reflect, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To accomplish this you'll need to store a view counter in a cookie with the user and then display based on that counter:

```
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['views'])) {
  $_SESSION['views'] = 0;
}
else {
  $_SESSION['views']++;
}
```

and then to display:

```
<?php if($_SESSION['views'] % 2 == 0): ?>
<a href="http://www.link1.tld"><img src="files/image1.jpg" border="0" /></a>
<? endif; ?>
<a href="http://www.link2.tld"><img src="files/image2.jpg" border="0" /></a>
<?php if($_SESSION['views'] % 2 == 1): ?>
<a href="http://www.link1.tld"><img src="files/image1.jpg" border="0" /></a>
<? endif; ?>
```

If the view counter is even it will print image1 first.  If it's odd it'll print it second.

Scaling this to more than two images could be done like this:

```
// map of images to URLs
$images = array(
  'image1.jpg' => 'http://www.link1.tld',
  'image2.jpg' => 'http://www.link2.tld',
  'image3.jpg' => 'http://www.link3.tld',
  'image4.jpg' => 'http://www.link4.tld',
);

// reorder the list of images based on the current view count
$ordered = array_merge(array_slice($images, $_SESSION['views'] % count($images)), array_slice($images, 0, $_SESSION['views'] % count($images)));
```

and then the display just loops through the ordered list:

```
<?php foreach($ordered as $image => $url): ?>
<a href="<?php echo $url; ?>"><img src="files/<?php echo $image; ?>" border="0" /></a>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Technically, you store the count values in the session, and the user receives a cookie with the session id, so that PHP can assign the session to the user, but session data is not stored on the client side (except on some implementations that do not use native PHP sessions like codeigniter)

Comment: Getting "Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by (output started at /home/wp-content/plugins/audio-player/audio-player.php:663) in /home/wp-content/themes/softpattern/sidebar.php on line 86"

If I disable plugin I get the same error for a different plugin. Where should the session_start() piece of the php be placed?

Comment: @scraft3613 session_start() must be called before any output is sent to the browser and should be moved out of your sidebar file, probably into wp-config.php.  See this for details: http://www.frank-verhoeven.com/using-session-in-wordpress/