# random images display

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, css

What is the simplest code or method to use when it comes to outputting multiple images?

Plus I want to style it in my css file.

I want to display them on my index.php

I have tried this already:
[Random image display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080787/random-image-display)

How do I make these images display randomly one at a time using php or javascript or html:

```
<img src="image_1"/>
<img src="image_2"/>
<img src="image_3"/>
<img src="image_4"/>
<img src="image_5"/>
```

Comment: Your going to have to give A LOT more detail.

Comment: And why that didn't work for you?

Comment: because my css file won't display it, i made a div tag with the id of image-lady

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should make an array of images like that:

```
<?php
    $images = array('img1.jpg', 'img2.jpg', 'img3.jpg');
?>
```

Then, you just get a random element from the array

```
<?php
    $random_image = array_rand($images);
?>
```

Then you can go right away displaying the image:

```
<img src="<?php echo $images[$random_image]; ?>" />
```

Hope this helps.