# Changing content when reload

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [random images display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10911452/random-images-display)

Have anyone see an image or other content that changing randomly when we reloading the page?
What is that? Can you tell me how to do that?

Comment: you have to code it via javascript or jquery, try some tutorials via web

Comment: Or when generating the page `<img src="img/<?=rand(1,100);?>.png">`

Comment: aaah, thanks mario, very thanks (y)

Answer (score 0):

Guess, something like this would do the trick.

```
/* div for your future image */
<div id="img"></div>
<script>

    window.onload = function(){

        /* array of urls to your images and random integer number between 0 and array's length-1 */
        var imgurls = [url1,url2,url3,...,urlN],
            randn = Math.floor(Math.random()*imgurls.length);

        /* create an HTML tag <img src="urlN"> in your div */
        document.getElementById('img').innerHTML = '<img src=' + imgurls[randn] + '>';
    }

</script>
```

Comment: It's fix bro, I have the answer on comment, thanks btw